# how to get hostname/servicename from HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, azure, http, kubernetes

I have two Node.js/Express services run on Azure/Kubernetes.
Then I send HTTP request to Service1 which is forwarding the request to Service2.
How Service2 knows that the request came from Service1?

HTTP/POST/GET => Service1 => Service2

console.log(request.headers.host) prints "Service2"

I do not want to modify the request in Service1 by adding extra info/data/fields.
So how do Service2 knows it came from Service1?

> > > > > update: I though this way I can reject some requests if they come from other services. Should I have it done through K8s Network Policy?

Comment: Why do you need to know this; what would the server do differently if the request did come from a specific client?  How would you implement this without Kubernetes, on bare metal, but with the two services running on different hosts?

Comment: I want to accept requests that come just from specific service/pod. Nobody else should hit Service2 endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

`Host` header is the address that the client is trying to reach, which is not what you want. `Origin` header will give you the source ip, but not a friendly service name, so to get that you would have to somehow map the IP back to a service, which is not simple to do since pods will typically get an new, unpredictable IP when they are created.

You could use the Kubernetes API to reverse lookup ip addresses for a service name, but that's a pretty bad design imo.

Ideally, you would have the client service add headers or data in the body with info about the calling service.

You might also be able to use a service mesh for Kubernetes (ie. istio, linkerd) which can inject information without needing to modify the original service.